# Managed Package Upgradation

Tags: managed-package

I have an App "**XYZ**" in my **Production** org, need to upgrade it with **latest version** is there will be any loss of data while upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the App.   I would do a test in a full sandbox if possible to verify.   Most apps do not destroy data and are more likely to abandon data and objects it does not need anymore.